# Heroku on facebook

Tags: facebook, heroku

I'd like to create an app on fb and thought I'd give Heroku a try. Whenever I try to click on Hosting URL...get one, it fails with the message:

Error processing request
There was an error creating a new Heroku platform for your App. Please try again later.

I've tried over several days with the same error message.

Surely I can't be the only one, any ideas anyone?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently working for me. If you're not verified on Heroku (no credit card added) you can't create more than 5 apps, so that might be worth checking.